# Java Selenium - Asserting only one CSS class is active after clearing filters on a search

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I want to know if there is a better way of refactoring my code for a scenario.
When the clear filters button is selected on a search results page this leaves one active state:

```
<li class="filter-options__item">
    <button class="filter-swatch filter-swatch--orange is-selected" data-filter="" data-filter-name="orange" data-ga-category="Colours Option" data-ga-action="orange" data-ga-label="10">
       <p class="filter-swatch__name"> orange</p> </button></li>
```

With the is-selected being the active state on the filter-swatch.

I currently have a count assertion to see the correct amount of filters are is-selected as below:

```
int count = 0;
    List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".filter-options__item > button"));

    for (Iterator<WebElement> i = elements.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
        WebElement element = i.next();
        String attr = element.getAttribute("class");

        if(attr.contains("is-selected")) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    Assert.assertEquals(1, count);
```

I was just wondering if this was best practice or if there was a better way of confirming this?

Comment: This question is opinion-based, hence off-topic for SO. Having said that, your approach seems fine. There is no "best practice" for this, just "does it work practice".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using loop to check the button has the class with 'is-selected', you can directly fetch the button element with the class specified as given below.

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".filter-options__item > button.is-selected"));
Assert.assertEquals(1, elements.size());
```

Comment: I simplified your code. There's no need to initialize a variable and then assign to it a couple lines later. There's also no need for a `count` variable here at all when you can easily use `elements.size()`.